# SSIS for each loops - how are part copied files handled?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014

I'm writing an SSIS package that runs on a schedule to poll a folder location.

The files will be picked up by a foreach loop, however these files are quite large and therefore take time to be copied into the directory.

I'd like to know how SSIS behaves when a foreach file loop is run on a directory with a file that is still being copied, will it skip over the file as it's not complete? Is there a danger that SSIS will attempt to load a part copied file?

Answer (score 1):

Nope there is no danger to the File. Nor will it be copied partially [Unless you are removing it after the copying of files is done.] That would be a disaster. ;)
It has nothing to do with the `Loop` being in place. The `File System Task` is the one you need to consider. It will act as if you are manual copying a file. What would happen if you did that? Also what else are you doing after you are done with the coping of the file from Source to the Destination folder matters like [Are you removing?]

In short "**NOTHING WOULD HAPPEN**". No partial files will be copied.

Comment: I ask about the loop, because it generates the list of files, if the loop doesn't pick it up then all is well, if it does then it could result in a file being archived that hasn't been loaded.

Comment: The Foreach Loop doesn't do anything except for looping... The File System Task processes the file. Ideally, the logic for archiving should be applied later to avoid such confusion.

Comment: So to confirm, the ForEach loop will detect a partially copied file?